# Convert string to time format

Tags: python

```
>>> x
['00:05:09.252', '00:05:42.244', '00:06:44.546']
```

How can I convert these string items to 'hh:mm:ss.uuu' time format, so that I can do time calculations in this format?

I read the docs, but everything seem to be explained in context of datetime and various time zones, while I just wanna do calculation in time format without writting my own function for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

given your data is strictly formatted to `hour:min:sec.usec`

(looks like they don't have [directives](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) to deal with microseconds in python `strptime`, so guess you have to supply the values yourself to `datetime.time`'s constructor)

```
import datetime
def timeconverter(timestring):
   hour, min, sec = timestring.split(':')
   sec, usec = sec.split('.')
   time = datetime.time(*[int(x, 10) for x in (hour, min, sec, usec)])
   return time
```

Comment: I somehow expected time manipulation in Python to be simpler. Thank for providing conversion function

Comment: @user2136786 it would be simple if there weren't any usecs :D

Comment: Yes, and Python doesn't have such formater, while there seem to be for microseconds. So, after doing calculations, if I want to convert these time objects to readable formats I can't again make it without changing a bit your converter to work in microseconds or perhaps something else

Comment: And to add, that `datetime.time` object doesn't seem to allow time calculations, but `datetime.datetime` does, and as mentioned I don't need the date. I'm heading to find simple package for this task, which will probably be `nptime` module

Answer (score 0):

Check out [strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) in the time module.

```
import time
t= time.strptime("00:05:42.244", "%H:%M:%S")
```

Do this if you don't care about the decimal part of the seconds. If you do care then the approuch used by thkang is a better solution.

Comment: `datetime.strptime('00:05:42.244', "%H:%M:%S.%f")` -> `datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 5, 42, 244000)`. To get `datetime.time` object, `.time()` method could be used. Note: it ignores timezones issues.